# Internal column name from Resource file

Tags: 2013, site-column, resource-files, field-definition

I have created a resource file to store project site column names and display names. What I find odd is that when the column is created the internal name remains `$Resources:Boris.SP.Abl.SiteColumns,XTestName` instead of just `XTest` which is the value of the `XTestName` key in the resource file.

Is that normal? If yes, how come the default `Title` site column is not internally named `$Resources:core,Title`?

Answer (score -1):

[SharePoint Internal Field Names – SharePoint 2010](https://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/)

[Reference list for SharePoint internal field names](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx)

Comment: How do your links in any way answer my question?